# Can we add on the help page which badges can be obtained multiple times?

Tags: feature-request, badges

The help pages for badges list them all, nice, but it is unclear which badges can be obtained multiple times. Could this be indicated, please?

For some this is rather obvious, like, "Enlightened: First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more" can obviously be obtained only once. But these descriptions are ambiguous examples: "Explainer: Edit and answer 1 question", "Revival: Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more", "Enthusiast: Visit the site each day for 30 consecutive days", or "Nice Answer: Answer score of 10 or more" ... just from that text there's no way of knowing that some of these are awarded multiple times, others are not.

Comment: The help pages are a central feature not specific to physics.SE, so this would probably find better attention at [meta.SE]

Comment: "Enlightened" can be awarded multiple times.

Answer (score 8):

A quick search on Meta Stack Exchange produces the FAQ thread

- [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)

which explicitly includes "awarded once", "awarded once per question", or "awarded multiple times" for all badges.

Including this into the formal descriptions in the help center is not necessarily obvious -- that resource needs to balance completeness with compactness and accessibility. If you feel strongly about this, the network-wide meta is probably a better place to campaign for this, though there are threads asking for this feature [dating back to at least 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/mark-which-badges-are-capable-of-being-won-1-time).